# How to view only procedure related grants in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, privileges, sql-grant

I want to see only grant privileges on a particular procedure in MySQL. [This documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html) shows all grants.

Is there a way to see grants only for a particular procedure in a db.

The below command gives all grants including select, update etc. :

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mysql.procs_priv A
WHERE A.Db = 'DatabaseName' AND A.User = 'root' AND 
      A.host = 'localhost' AND A.Routine_name = 'ProcedureName' AND 
      FIND_IN_SET('Grant', A.proc_priv);
```

Comment: This works but I thought there is some way using GRANT keyword as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to **grant execute privileges** on specific procedure:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE schema_name.proc_name TO 'user_name';
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-routine-privileges)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you want to create a procedure called MyFirstProc and you wanted to grant ALL users the ability to EXECUTE this procedure. You would run the following GRANT statement:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE MyFirstProc TO '*'@'localhost';
```